# Win10 error booting when Win7 installed on second SSD

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, boot, multi-boot, bootloader

I've unplugged main SSD with Windows10 and installed Windows 7 on secondary on board SSD.
When I plugged in main SSD, Windows 10 failed to boot.

It runs disk checker over and over. I've even deleted Windows 7 and formatted the partition, but without success.

Comment: Did you have Windows 10 also (and perhaps inadvertently) installed on the second drive so that the second drive was needed to start?  I am not sure how you fix this if you formatted the second drive.

Comment: CHKDSK should allow you to stop it with a counter. "Press any key..." usually 10 seconds to comply.

Comment: No, the idea was to keep one drive one OS, since I prefer selection OS via selecting the drive to boot. However, Win10 seems to be smarter than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, and I used a software program for making backup of disks and partitions called  **Macrium Reflect**. It has a 'fix boot problems' option.
This sometimes helps, with Windows 10 and 8, but not always, with Windows 7.